# Crashlytics Device State In background on iOS only

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm using Crashlytics to get repports of exceptions & crashes for a unity game which is both released on Android and iOS.

I'm wondering if I can trust the Device State "In Background" on iOS.

I have the exact same error for both ios and android, but the ios repport that the app is in background way more.

Android:

[image]

iOS:

[image]

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. It's tough to tell based on the information provided. In general, we've found our data to be accurate, but there isn't a clear case as to why this is inaccurate given that OS handle backgrounding differently.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your reply. The example I provided is one of many. Almost all of our Non-Fatal issues on iOS have such a high "App In Background" rate while not the case on Android. That's why I asked about this. The "App In Background" rate isn't related to any particular iOS version or device model.